# Trouble scaling rectangle to specified scale in AS3

Tags: actionscript-3

I've been scratching my head for the past couple hours trying to figure this out. I've created a parent Sprite gameBoard1 and a child sprite Block1 inside. I'm using a click function to advance the level of the game. What I want to do is have the dimensions of gameBoard1 increase, which maintaining the dimensions of Block1. This works, but of course, gameBoard1 quickly does not fit on the screen, so I'm trying scaling. I've generated my scale factor:

```
var rescaleX:Number = resizeBoardX / gameBoard1Width;
```

And I want to use that number to adjust the scale of gameBoard1:

```
gameBoard1.scaleX = rescaleX;
gameBoard1.scaleY = rescaleX;
```

What ends up happening is gameBoard1 (along with Block1) appears smaller and smaller on each "level" Since I'm calculating the rescaleX value each time there's a new level, gameBoard1 should be displaying as roughly the same size for each level and it's just the children (Block1) that should appear to get smaller because of the actual size of gameBoard1.

This is my first game and I'm just tinkering around, but this has got me pretty clueless.

```
var YtoXratio:Number = stage.stageHeight / stage.stageWidth;
var resizeBoardX:Number = stage.stageWidth * 0.95;
var resizeBoardY:Number = stage.stageHeight * 0.95;
trace ("resizeBoardX and Y are 95% of the stage width/height " + resizeBoardX + " x " + resizeBoardY);

var Xcenter:Number = stage.stageWidth / 2 - resizeBoardX / 2;
var Ycenter:Number = stage.stageHeight / 2 - resizeBoardY / 2;

var gameBoard1:Sprite = new Sprite;
gameBoard1.graphics.beginFill(0xFF0000); 
gameBoard1.graphics.drawRect(0, 0, stage.stageWidth , stage.stageHeight); 
//gameBoard1.graphics.endFill(); 
addChild(gameBoard1); 

gameBoard1.x = Xcenter;
gameBoard1.y = Ycenter; 
gameBoard1.scaleX = 0.95; 
gameBoard1.scaleY = gameBoard1.scaleX;

var block1:Shape = new Shape; 
block1.graphics.beginFill(0x0000FF); 
block1.graphics.drawRect(0, 0, 400, 400); 
block1.graphics.endFill();
gameBoard1.addChild(block1); 

var gameBoard1Width:Number = gameBoard1.width;
var gameBoard1Height:Number = gameBoard1Width * YtoXratio;

gameBoard1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, nextLevel);
function nextLevel (e:MouseEvent):void{
gameBoard1Width = gameBoard1Width + 100;
gameBoard1Height = gameBoard1Width * YtoXratio;

gameBoard1.width = gameBoard1Width;
gameBoard1.height = gameBoard1Height;

var rescaleX:Number = resizeBoardX / gameBoard1Width; 
trace("the scale ratio should be " + rescaleX);
gameBoard1.scaleX = rescaleX;
gameBoard1.scaleY = rescaleX;

trace("gameBoard1Width =" + gameBoard1Width + "  gameBoard1Height =" + gameBoard1Height);
trace("the scaled gameboard should be " + gameBoard1Width * rescaleX + " x " + gameBoard1Height);
trace("the scaled gameBoard is " + gameBoard1.width + " x " + gameBoard1.height);
}
```

Comment: Is there a reason why `block1` is a child of `gameBoard` if you don't want it to scale/move along with `gameBoard`?    I'm wondering what the purpose of gameBoard is,  a it just seems to be a red background?

Comment: Eventually, there will be many child objects on gameBoard. The red background of gameBoard is only a placeholder atm, it will eventually be just a transparent rectangle, filled with child objects (pieces), and as the gameBoard scales, so will all the pieces on the gameBoard.  What I'm getting at is the ability to resize, zoom, and pan the gameBoard at higher levels where the gameBoard will be too large to fit on screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Be aware that using `stage.stageWidth` (and height) is a dynamic value and changes as the contents change (the same as working with any other `MovieClip`).  If you want a static value, either store it when you first load, or use the compiled values, which are stored in the [`this.loaderInfo.width`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/LoaderInfo.html) (and height).

The following code will create your board, and resize the contents to the precalculated dimensions defined by the background.  Every time you add another block to the board, the board will resize to match the background.

```
var bg:Shape; // the visible background of our game board.
var board:Sprite; // the container for our blocks, which we'll rescale

addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, init);

function init(e:Event):void {
    // Make sure we have a populated loader by referencing one of its properties.
    var ready:Boolean;
    try { ready = (this.loaderInfo.width > 0) ? true : false; } catch (e:Error) {}

    if (ready) {
        removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, init); // Remove further frame tests.

        // Create the Background
        bg = new Shape();
        bg.graphics.beginFill(0xFF0000);
        bg.graphics.drawRect(0, 0, this.loaderInfo.width * 0.9, this.loaderInfo.height * 0.9);
        bg.graphics.endFill();
        bg.x = this.loaderInfo.width / 2 - bg.width / 2;
        bg.y = this.loaderInfo.height / 2 - bg.height / 2;
        addChild(bg);

        // Create the board
        board = new Sprite();
        board.x = bg.x;
        board.y = bg.y;
        addChild(board);
        board.addChild(createBlock());

        // Create a button to advance the level
        var txt:TextField = new TextField();
        txt.text = "Next Level";
        addChild(txt);
        txt.addEventListener("click", nextLevel);
    }
}

function nextLevel(e:Event):void {
    // Create a new block
    var block:Shape = createBlock();
    board.addChild(block);
    block.x = block.width * (board.numChildren - 1);
    trace("Now on level " + board.numChildren);

    // Resize the board to fit the background.
    if (board.width > bg.width) {
        board.width = bg.width;
        board.scaleY = board.scaleX;
    }
}

function createBlock():Shape {
    var block:Shape = new Shape();
    block.graphics.beginFill(Math.floor(Math.random() * (1+0xFFFFFF-0x000000)) + 0x000000);
    block.graphics.drawRect(0,0,200,200);
    block.graphics.endFill();
    return block;
}
```

Comment: Hmm, interesting, I'll have to play around with it a bit more. I don't want the board to resize when a new block is added, but for the whole board to resize on player control regardless of how many blocks are present. I think there's enough info here for me to make some progress though, thanks!